# Twitter API Video Upload with url

Tags: node.js, typescript, twitter-api-v2

In twitter API """ https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-append """

While Uploading a video through this API i have created a buffer to get the chuck of the data and append the data to the API ,so I am getting a S3 link when I upload a video and I am downloading it as response and converting into a chucks of data for the media Upload as stated in documentation .

```
export const downloadFile = async (url: string): Promise<AxiosResponse<Buffer>> => {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
};
```

```
`const readFile = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await downloadFile(url);
    console.info('data', response);
    return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      let data = Buffer.alloc(0);
      let mediaId = undefined;
      // @ts-ignore
      response.data.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
      });
      // @ts-ignore
      response.data.on('end', async () => {
        resolve(data);
      });
      // @ts-ignore
      response.data.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        reject(false);
      });
    });
  };`
```

So without Reading the buffer is there any way we can send the s3 cdn uploaded URL to Twitter as data so that it could it rather than doing it manually from the back end. Is there any way I can send data as link not data chunks. please help